# Rotate image when a link clicked With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a table with rows i want to rotate Arrow image to -90 degree for each row that clicked.i wrote some codes but the codes worked for all arrows in my table.not for each that clicked. how can i do that? here is my Snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.subRow {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;

}
.content {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption>Test Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr align="center" class="parentRow">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left-red.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parentRow">
       <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left-red.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS `transform`:

- http://www.cssportal.com/blog/rotating-images-with-css/

Whenever the link is clicked, we apply a new class to the parent of the image called `active` and rotate the image when the class is applied:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
    $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.active img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.subRow {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;

}
.content {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption>Test Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr align="center" class="parentRow">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left-red.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parentRow">
       <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left-red.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to have animations you can use `transition`:

```
transition: transform 0.5s;
```

Add this to the `.active img` class

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, best of luck in your journey through HTML / CSS / JS :)!

Answer (score 1):

Make a CSS class like this

```
.rotate{
   transform: rotate(-90deg)
}
```

and your JS like

```
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('img').toggleClass('rotate')
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
    $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

And if you want your arrow to animate, add following in your CSS code

```
td .show img {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("rotate");
  });
});
```

```css
.subRow {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;

}
.content {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display:none;
}
.show.rotate>img{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption>Test Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr align="center" class="parentRow">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left-red.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parentRow">
       <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left-red.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```